# Combining Babel Library in SWC Next.js: Integrate external Babel-dependent package while preserving SWC compilation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babel-loader, swc, swc-compiler

In my Next.js project, the primary compiler is SWC. However, I have a component that relies on an external library compiled with Babel. Is it feasible to configure Next.js to use Babel exclusively for this particular component while continuing to use SWC for the rest of the project?

I have not tried anything yet